# Why rep doesn't increase after upvote?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Why when I vote up a skeet answer his reputation doesn't change? I can confirm that happens,tried it more than once.

Comment: Exactly how many times did you try it? http://twitter.com/jonskeet/status/3281095099

Answer (score 13, accepted):

He has hit the reputation cap for today.

You can only get 200 rep per day from upvotes, and he has already gotten that.

Plus .. he is Jon Skeet, he don't need no stinkin upvotes!

Comment: I suspect he spend 80% of the day on his 200 cap :-) If you want to upvote him and make it count, you need to get in early.